# html object tag should we specify type as video/mp4 to play mp4 videos?

Tags: html, video, mp4

I know that object tag embeds objects in html and useful for playing videos/audios.
When we specify object with type="video/mpeg" does this use the default player in the device

I am having an issue in playing mp4 files. When i use object tag.
It is able to play mpeg-2 transport stream though.

Also the device player specs says they support mp4.

Am i missing anything here.

Answer (score 4):

You might get help from [this](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) website mentioned in this answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299347/how-do-i-embed-a-mp4-movie-into-my-html).

**Edit:**

html *object* tag has some limitations like the other tags used to play videos. I think [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp) will give you a more clear idea. There you'll see that the best solution is to use 3 different methods together like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
<object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
<embed src="movie.swf" width="320" height="240">
Your browser does not support video
</embed>
</object>
</video>
```

In this example, The HTML 5 *video* element tries to play the video either in mp4, ogg, or webm formats. If this fails, the code "falls back" to try the *object* element. If this also fails, it "falls back" to the *embed* element.
And the easiest way to display videos in HTML is to use YouTube.
Anyway, you'll understand it better if you read the whole thing there.

Comment: thanks....it is useful... to be specific i am wondering what player will be called in a device say laptop or tv by default if we have a browser running on it

Comment: I actually don't have good idea about samsung tv browsers. But there must be some way to see which player is set as the default media player and also to set other players as default. BTW, have you tried JW player yet?

Comment: not yet..but searched the net after u mentioned it ...looks very compatible with most of the browsers....will have a look into tht...thanks for your continued response...was very helpful...