# How do I use an Object URL with Videogular

Tags: angularjs, html, videogular

I am trying to use an Object URL with Videogular and a 0 second video shows up. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
$http.get("/Video/small.mp4").success(function(data) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'video/mp4' })
    val objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    controller.config.sources =
        [{ src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(objectUrl), type: "video/mp4" }]
});
```

If I don't use an Object URL then everything works as expected:

```
controller.config.sources = [
     { src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("/Video/small.mp4"), type: "video/mp4" }
]
```

I am eventually going to store the video in indexeddb which is why I am interested in playing the video using an Object URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732567/html-object-tag-should-we-specify-type-as-video-mp4-to-play-mp4-videos take look at this

Comment: @pankajparkar Thanks for the links. Unfortunately none of the articles linked off that answer address Object URLs. The articles address the <object> tag which is different.

Comment: Did you tried without $sce.trustAsResourceUrl? I don't think that a blob needs to be trusted since is an object. If it doesn't works maybe you need to write a plugin and access to the video element source through API. mediaElement.src to change the source.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this? I encountered the same issue.