# knitr mp4 movie embedding does not work on Windows XP

Tags: html, windows, html5-video, mp4, knitr

I knit a Rmd file (to html) with a chunk producing a mp4 movie :

````
```{r clock, fig.width=7, fig.height=6, fig.show='animate'}
par(mar = rep(3, 4))
for (i in seq(pi/2, -4/3 * pi, length = 12)) {
    plot(0, 0, pch = 20, ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE)
    arrows(0, 0, cos(i), sin(i))
    axis(1, 0, "VI"); axis(2, 0, "IX")
    axis(3, 0, "XII"); axis(4, 0, "III"); box()
}
```
````

`knitr`generates the following html code for embedding the mp4 movie :

```
<p><video   controls="controls" loop="loop"><source src="figure/clock.mp4" type="video/mp4" />video of chunk clock</video></p>
```

The mp4 movie is well created in the figure subfolder but it does not appear in the html output when I open it with a Windows XP machine using either Chrome, Firefox or Explorer.

Here is a (temporary) example : http://stla.overblog.com/ellipse-chart-test - this is not the "clock" example but this is exactly the same rendering problem. I see the movie with Chrome on a Windows Vista machine, but not with my Windows XP machine.

What is the explanation ? Is it really a problem with the OS or with browser versions ?

Comment: I cannot say with total certainty for Windows XP, but i know for Mac OS that browsers use OS features to play (some) video formats. This is a licensing issue: MP4 (or, more precisely h.264) is a format protected by patents. The OS vendors usually license those CODECs, so that the applications running on it don't have to. When Windows XP was released, h.264 didn't exist. Go figure... If that answers your question, I'll gladly write a more complete answer.

Comment: @likeitlikeit That would mean that it is impossible to embed this file in html for a XP user, even with another html code ? (assuming we do not modify the file)

Comment: From your description and what I know about playing web media on different OSes, this might very well be the case.

Comment: @likeitlikeit Ok. I asked friends to try and indeed it never works for XP users. Nice if you'd write an answer.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent FYI -- in the next version of knitr, I will use OGG instead of MP4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Browsers **really** use the OS to perform some media decoding tasks. Work around it by **a)** providing alternate media streams **b)** using the most compatible media format for your audience **c)** using a plugin (i.e. Flash), or **d)** recommend installing an MP4 plugin.

This is in fact a 'problem' with the OS. Many browsers, just as some other programs on a particular platform, use the operating system resources to acomplish a given task. This is particularly true when it comes to procedures protected by intellectual property rights.

Your codec (h.264 aka "MP4") happens to be a particulary fiercely fought over piece of IP. Thus, browsers don't go to lengths to licence the IP at hand, but rather use the licenced codecs of the host system.

In your case, Windows XP happens not to be able to decode the media format of your video, and the browser doesn't seem to be able to do that by itself.

Your alternatives now:

- Give additional media streams with your `video` tag (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#.3Cvideo.3E_element_examples) for an example)
- Trying to find out what *browser* the majority of users is using on XP, then choose a natively supported format (either `webm` for Chrome or `ogg` for Firefox)
- Just use Flash to play the MP4 (as in the pre-HTML5 days)
- Telling users to install an OS-level plugin to play h.264; you could even do that in the fallback text. I won't recommend a specific product, but there are many.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works well with a `webm` video and the Chrome browser: http://stla.overblog.com/ellipse-chart-test2